# Incorrect syntax near the keyword "Primary"

Tags: c#, sql, database, silverlight, service

I have this error message but i cannot find any wrongdoing, help?

```
const string sql = @"SELECT PrimarySchool,TopHonour,Cca,TopStudent,TopAggregate,TopImage FROM Primary";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

primary is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in TSQL. Make it `SELECT ...(snipped)... FROM [Primary]"` to escape it and indicate you mean the object named Primary.

Comment: that solved my problem thanks! and turns out thats the root of my problem for the error with my method...